# Replacing smart quotes in unix with single quotes using sed on LInux Suse 12

Tags: linux, sed, replace, cron, quotes

If I run this as a normal user

```
#!/bin/bash
echo This is a smart quote â fixed using previous method | sed "s/â/'/g"
QUOTES="\xE2\x80\x9C|\xE2\x80\x9D"
echo This is a fixed smart quote â fixed using new method | sed "s/[$QUOTES]/'/g"
```

The smart quote is replaced using either method when running the script at the prompt as expected

If I run the script as a cron job I get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

using either method

Why would sed run differently in cron ??

In Windows the comment line in question is:

FTX368   20/09/2012  VV   10798 - Add 'Benefit Maintenance’ button.

So its a smart single end-quote - ASCII 146 - Hex 92

Comment: What character-set are you using? Your **smart quote** to me looks like a Scandinavian a, the one with the little o on top.

Comment: What is the output of `locale` under cron? Vs what is it normally?

Comment: In Windows the comment line in question is

Comment: Aha normally LC_CTYPE="POSIX" but as cron it is en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I added

LC_CTYPE="POSIX"

to my script and now both solutions work fine when run as cron or not !

I didn't know about the locale command thanks o11c for that